# Square transactions Api - retrieving request results

Tags: api, transactions, square

Please help me understand what I need to do next. I am using square transactions API to accept payments on an ecommerce website. I got the nonce from the form generated and I want I get the following response below. I now need to retrieve values from this response and store them in variables so that I can move on to create a purchase order for the order to be fulfilled.

```
SquareConnect\Model\ChargeResponse Object
(
    [errors:protected] => 
    [transaction:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Transaction Object
        (
            [id:protected] => ...
            [location_id:protected] => ...
            [created_at:protected] => 2018-08-05T15:45:48Z
            [tenders:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SquareConnect\Model\Tender Object
                        (
                            [id:protected] => ...
                            [location_id:protected] => ..
                            [transaction_id:protected] => ...
                            [created_at:protected] => 2018-08-05T15:45:48Z
                            [note:protected] => Online Transaction
                            [amount_money:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Money Object
                                (
                                    [amount:protected] => 20448
                                    [currency:protected] => USD
                                )

                            [tip_money:protected] => 
                            [processing_fee_money:protected] => 
                            [customer_id:protected] => 
                            [type:protected] => CARD
                            [card_details:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\TenderCardDetails Object
                                (
                                    [status:protected] => CAPTURED
                                    [card:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Card Object
                                        (
                                            [id:protected] => 
                                            [card_brand:protected] => VISA
                                            [last_4:protected] => 1111
                                            [exp_month:protected] => 
                                            [exp_year:protected] => 
                                            [cardholder_name:protected] => 
                                            [billing_address:protected] => 
                                            [fingerprint:protected] =>...
                                        )

                                    [entry_method:protected] => KEYED
                                )

                            [cash_details:protected] => 
                            [additional_recipients:protected] => 
                        )

                )

            [refunds:protected] => 
            [reference_id:protected] => 
            [product:protected] => EXTERNAL_API
            [client_id:protected] => 
            [shipping_address:protected] => 
            [order_id:protected] => 
        )
)
```

I just need the result of the transaction confirming that the card is charged

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Getter methods to access the private attributes. For example: https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/docs/Model/ChargeResponse.md